# Having two if condition

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently studying if condition statement and it is one of my weakest topic ever. Here in this code below, there are two if conditions and I would like to know, how do we find the output of this? I know how to get the output when there is one if. But what about having two if?

```
function exercise3(){

   var x, y, z;

   x = 20;

   y = 30;

   z = 50;



   if ((x - 10) < y) {

       if (y - 5 > x) {

            alert (z - x);

       }

       else {

            alert (z - 5);

       }

    }

}

exercise3();
```

Comment: There is nothing unique in having 2 nested `if` statements.

Comment: The 2nd if is nested within another if. So if you meet the 1st condition you follow through with the next condition and so on. Are you getting unexpected results?

Comment: @zer00ne no, I am curious how do we obtain the results of this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is referred as Nested If statement. Basically you deal with the most outer block first before the going into the inner block. You would **only go into the inner block if the condition in the statement is true**.

Your statement condition is true

```
if ((x - 10) < y) {
...
}
```

Hence you would **proceed to read through**.

Take note generally to make it more readable better use If else statements rather than if alone as the execution will proceed to check the next if statement with is actually block one and block two (one by one) bringing about slow execution in long written statements.

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Cheers, happy learning and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

That is the same as this, if it helps you understand better. The below snippet is just for example purpose, do not follow that. You need to use nested `if` conditionals.

```
function exercise3(){
  var x, y, z;
  x = 20;
  y = 30;
  z = 50;

  // The first if and nested if from your snippet
  if ((x - 10) < y) && (y - 5) > x) {
    alert(z - x);
  }

  // The first if and nested else from your snippet
  if ((x - 10) < y && (y - 5) <= x) {
    alert (z - 5);
  }    
}

exercise3();
```